# Why does my 'get' request turn into a 'post' request when I add params (rails, minitest)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm trying to write an paginated index action in a rails app. This is my controller code

```
def index
  @pokemons = Pokemon.all.limit(params[:limit]).offset(params[:offset])
end
```

This works perfectly in my development server when I make requests through a browser.

In my tests, however, I'm having trouble calling the index action.

When I run my test as below, a GET request is made that's routed to #index.

```
test "should return paginated index" do
  get pokemons_url, as: :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

However as soon as I add params related to pagination, like so...

```
test "should return paginated index" do
  get pokemons_url, params: {limit: 10, offset: 0}, as: :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

...the request received by my server becomes a POST instead of a GET and it's routed to my #create action.

Here's my `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pokemons
end
```

and here's the relevant output from `rails routes`:

```
                             pokemons GET    /pokemons(.:format)                                                                               pokemons#index
                                     POST   /pokemons(.:format)                                                                               pokemons#create
                             pokemon GET    /pokemons/:id(.:format)                                                                           pokemons#show
                                     PATCH  /pokemons/:id(.:format)                                                                           pokemons#update
                                     PUT    /pokemons/:id(.:format)                                                                           pokemons#update
                                     DELETE /pokemons/:id(.:format)                                                                           pokemons#destroy
```

Why does adding params to the 'get' method in Minitest turn my GET request into a POST request? How can I send a GET from Minitest that includes my pagination parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameters are intended to be simple query string parameters you should pass them to the routing helper:

```
test "should return paginated index" do
  get pokemons_url(limit: 10, offset: 0), as: :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why `params:` is causing this to be processed as a post request. But typically you would only really do that if you're testing a form that sends get requests (like a search form).

Answer (score 0):

please show me the `routes.rb` and your define `pokemons_url`
you must be sure `pokemons_url` same `pokemons_index_path` if your controller name is PokemonsController

Comment: Ok, question has been edited